# The command 'adb root' works, but 'adb remount' results in "Operation not permitted" message

Tags: adb

I'm trying to remount `/system` to copy some files to it. I tried the following with `adb`:

```
adb root
adb remount
```

The first command works fine (because my phone is rooted), but the second tells me that the operation is not permitted. If I open an `adb shell` and run `su` I can access the system folder without problems.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you please [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/52443/edit) your question and add the exact error message? That might provide some clue.

Comment: @Izzy It is the exact error message, there's nothing else in there.

Comment: Nothing about "not permitted *on production devices*" or the like? Usually, it should not even permit `adb root`, even if the device is rooted. Are you sure `adb root` worked?

Comment: @Izzy Are there other ways to test if root worked?

Comment: `adb shell`, then type `su -`. If your rooting process was successful, you should see a popup on your device asking to approve the su request − and having confirmed that, your shell prompt should switch from a `$` to a `#`.

Comment: @Izzy Yep, that works fine.

Comment: OK. So do you consider your issue solved (i.e. was the question rather "How can I check whether rooting was successful?")? If so: Maybe you update your question, and then I sum up an answer?

Comment: @Izzy No, my question is still about `adb remount` not working despite me being a super user.

Comment: Understood. So did it work from the shell after explicitly making yourself root (`su -`)? The `adb root` command AFAIK doesn't switch to a root shell, but should restart the ADB daemon in root mode, which officially is not supported on production builds – which could be the reason your original approach failed.

Answer (score 4):

Some phones just don't allow remounting via `adb remount`.

Mount as RW:

```
adb shell su -c "mount -o rw,remount,rw /system"
```

Mount as RO:

```
adb shell su -c "mount -o ro,remount,ro /system"
```

Also you could use the [Adbd Insecure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.adbd) app, but it's not free.

Comment: Chainfire mentions in the app description, that the APK is available for free from the XDA forum. I copied the link for convenience: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1687590

Comment: su: invalid uid/gid '-c'

Comment: `mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts`

Answer (score 2):

Some builds require the following adb commands to be run first

```
adb root
adb disable-verity
adb reboot
```

Then once device reboots,

```
adb root
adb remount
```

Comment: C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb disable-verity

disable-verity only works for userdebug builds

Answer (score 1):

Could be that SELinux getting in the way. Try this:

```
getenforce
```

If it returns `1` or `Enable`, do:

```
setenforce 0
```

Then try your command again.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to usually work for me:

```
adb root
```

You will see a message as `Restarting adbd as root`. Unplug the device from USB, connect again and enter:

```
adb remount
```

**Troubleshooting:**

```
adb shell
```

Confirm that you are root if you see `#` shell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, some devices have permanent (kernel-level I think) write-protection for the `/system` mount, so even if you're root, you still can't remount it in RW mode. You have to restart the device without this protection, which is done differently depending on the device.

Comment: This was about the Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error if I try to use `adb remount`. The reason is some kind of protection but can be bypassed by using a root shell.

The following should work (you may type `exit` to quit the shell):

```
adb shell
su -
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

Answer (score 0):

Get [adbd insecure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.adbd) from google play store. It helps give write access to custom ROMs that have it secured my the manufacturers.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem statement**
From the terminal, I connected to my STB using ADB connect IP address of the STB and after executing ADB root, I tried executing ADB remount. I was stuck with the below error message in my terminal.

Android 9 userdebug version execute ADB remount appear:
remount of the / superblock failed: Permission denied
remount failed

**Pre-requisite:**
The first thing is you need to carry out the below pre-requisite setup,

- Need to have a laptop either Mac or windows with ADB installed or in case it's not installed get it downloaded from ADB  but if you have windows well and good.
- USB to USB Male( Male -2- Mable cable).
- One end of the USB is connected to the STB USB port (White Color port) and then another end is connected to your laptop USB port.
- After the above setup is completed, from your command prompt or terminal type adb devices, if it lists the device connected with its serial number that means your connection setup is perfect.

**Solution**

- **First** thing from the terminal type below command
  adb reboot fastboot  //This will reboot your STB
  fastboot flashing unlock // After STB reboots and you see the google android preloader, run this command
  fastboot reboot //After the above command execute this.
- **Next**
  adb root //After STB reboots and you see the google android preloader, run this command
  adb disable-verity //Immediately after that run this command
  adb reboot //Immediately after that run this command
- **Last** //disable Selinux and mount dir
  adb root //After STB reboots and you see the google android preloader, run this command
  adb shell setenforce 0  //Immediately after that run this command
  adb remount //Immediately after that run this command
- After the last set of commands you could see the remount works successfully,
  now either reboot your STB ie adb reboot

Answer (score -1):

Try running the command `reboot disemmcwp` and re-rooting after the reboot. Then do your thing