# Is there a definite way to know if my phone supports USB-OTG or not?

Tags: root-access, hardware, usb-on-the-go, hardware-requirements

I have a Samsung Galaxy Win phone, rooted and with adbd insecure installed ([using the link here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52443/the-command-adb-root-works-but-adb-remount-results-in-operation-not-permit)).

This is the information shown by the USB OTG Checker app:

[image]

I have added the [android.hardware.usb.host.xml file](https://github.com/452/USBHIDTerminal/wiki/How-to-enable-USB-host-API-support) into `/system/etc/permissions` folder and the [USB-OTG app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.faitaujapon.otg&hl=en) says that my phone is now OTG capable (before, it showed that OTG is not supported only due to the missing xml file).

When I connect OTG cable and a USB drive, nothing happens at all. Same with a USB mouse. The [USB Device Info app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aws.apps.usbDeviceEnumerator&hl=en) says nothing is connected. It's possible USB OTG hardware itself is missing from this phone, but it is very difficult to find any information about this model at all (it was really difficult to get this phone rooted in the first place).

Is there a definitive way to know whether the phone supports OTG or not? Is there a Java function that I could call which would confirm OTG, or is there any function that would crash if OTG is not present at the hardware level?

**EDIT 1:**

Output after doing the procedure mentioned in the comment:

"Do with root privileges: `cd /sdcard && find /sys | sort >1`. Connect USB. Then: `find /sys | sort >2 && diff 1 2`. This will let you know how kernel treats USB hardware."

```
--- 1
+++ 2
@@ -17357,10 +17357,15 @@
 /sys/kernel/debug/binder/failed_transaction_log
 /sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc
 /sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/19015
-/sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/19034
 /sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/21683
 /sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/22063
 /sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/22112
+/sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/22152
+/sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/22166
+/sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/22185
+/sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/22197
+/sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/22212
+/sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/22224
 /sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/2788
 /sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/2796
 /sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/2797
@@ -17402,12 +17407,7 @@
 /sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/5383
 /sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/5972
 /sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/6076
-/sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/6343
 /sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/6358
-/sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/6370
-/sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/6382
-/sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/6397
-/sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/6410
 /sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/6423
 /sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/6439
 /sys/kernel/debug/binder/proc/6479
```

Comment: Check the kernel log via `dmesg` before and after connecting an USB OTG device. Usually you should see something in the kernel log if a new USB device is detected. Another potential reason why OTG does not work is if the USB port does not supply power. Try to use an active powered hub in between.

Comment: @Robert do I run that on the phone? How do I run this? Typing this in a terminal app says `/system/bin/sh: dmseg: not found`

Comment: Execute it via adb, and type it correctly then it will work.

Comment: Duplicate: [How can I determine if my device has USB Host Mode (OTG) support?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36887/how-can-i-determine-if-my-device-has-usb-host-mode-otg-support)

Answer (score 2):

USB OTG is a hardware capability. Software can't tell if the hardware has this capability or not if it's not configured to do so. The app you show is just confirming the presence of `host.xml` file that you have put yourself. Also you can confirm that form `adb shell`:

```
~$ pm list features | grep usb.host
# OR
~$ dumpsys package features | grep usb.host
```

For USB OTG to work, first your kernel should create a hardware entry in `/sys` as per device-tree mapping when you connect USB drive.
Secondly a device should be populated in `/dev/bus/usb/...` (and `/dev/block/...` if it's a storage device). It depends on `uevent` configuration on your ROM. Or you may also manually create device using `mknod`.

Thirdly you need to place `host.xml` file so that OS and apps can know that USB OTG support is present on device. Now apps can access USB device directly (provided that proper permissions are set on device path and node) by making use of host mode [APIs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/package-summary).
Lastly if your ROM supports auto-mounting USB Storage devices (available on Android 6+), you should have an entry for `vold` in `fstab`. See [How to disable USB OTG on Android 8.1?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217355/218526.)

As suggested, your Edit 1 shows that the changes in `sysfs` after attaching USB are only in `debugfs`, no hardware is detected by kernel.

One last thing you can do is to use a powered USB hub as suggested by @[Robert](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/2241) in comment. Also check `dmesg` log for kernel messages and `logcat` for `USBManager` and `USBHost` messages in Java stack. If no hardware is detected then your hardware or at least kernel doesn't support USB.