# How to know if USB drive was detected using OTG from dmesg output?

Tags: adb, samsung, usb, usb-on-the-go

I am trying to get OTG to work with my phone (Samsung Galaxy Win SHV-E500L, [previous question here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218575/is-there-a-definite-way-to-know-if-my-phone-supports-usb-otg-or-not))

I have used an externally powered USB hub and connected it to an OTG cable connecting it to my phone, and the USB drive is inserted into the hub

Here is the dmesg message before connecting the USB drive:

https://pastebin.com/29fHksyz

This is the content of the dmesg.log file.

Here it is after:

https://pastebin.com/rGdgzfBm

The two look different so it must have detected something, but I am not sure what to look for. How can I determine if my phone can use OTG or not from these messages?

EDIT 1---

Here is the output after doing as instructed in the comment :

> Please post the output in understandable form. There is a time frame
>   missing in between both of your outputs. Do dmesg -C; dmesg -w 2>&1 |
>   tee /sdcard/dmesg.log. Immediately connect USB. Within a second or
>   two, as soon as some output comes from kernel, break the command (Ctrl
>   ^C). Share dmesg.log file.

https://pastebin.com/BKaPCT3L

Comment: Maybe "external MMC(SD)" On/Off

Comment: Please post the output in understandable form. There is a time frame missing in between both of your outputs. Do `dmesg -C; dmesg -w 2>&1 | tee /sdcard/dmesg.log`. Immediately connect USB. Within a second or two, as soon as some output comes from kernel, break the command (Ctrl ^C). Share `dmesg.log` file.

Comment: @IrfanLatif You mean connect USB first, then give the command `dmesg -C; dmesg -w 2>&1 | tee /sdcard/dmesg.log` then immediately disconnect USB as soon as I see some text? Did I get it correctly? Or do I give the command first then connect USB?