# Android tablet says it's OTG compatible, but it won't detect other devices when plugged in

Tags: root-access, usb-on-the-go

I have a proprietary tablet that's been secured. It's a mediatek **mt8163**, with **Android 8.0**.

It's a "Managed Device" as android likes to call it. Anyways, I ended up being able to create a hack that installs an app, and I then gained root access.

When I run an OTG checker app, it says the device is OTG capable/compatible. However, when I connect the OTG cable to any device, it will only charge, it won't recognize that another device has been connected. Therefor I can't transfer data or anything of the sort, which is my goal.

Is there any setting that I may be able to access in the terminal that will fully enable OTG? I have Super User access in the terminal, so anything I can do to troubleshoot OTG from here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mediatek devices rarely support OTG

Comment: @alecxs Could the OTG checker just be giving me a false positive?

Comment: I don't know that app but it may give you separate info about hardware- and software support. additional software may required

Comment: @alecxs That's kinda what I was thinking. I just can't find any other software and/or settings that may help with this.

Comment: search for other users with same issue same device sure you will find solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a definite way to know if my phone supports USB-OTG or not?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218575/is-there-a-definite-way-to-know-if-my-phone-supports-usb-otg-or-not)